# Production of mind maps

Tags: semantics

On [SpanishD!ct](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/216673/mind-maps-for-increasing-vocabulary/blog/feed), an interesting discussion about the use of mind maps in language learning has arisen. (This has been trimmed down from [a question on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/26060/1407).)

Are there mind maps such as these that are created using corpora, and are they created using distributional or semantic criteria, or both?

[image: "tell" mind map]

[image: "talk" mind map]

Comment: They can be created according to any criteria you want to program them for. A lot of criteria are available, including some that are reasonable, some that are measurable, and some  that are both. The problem is the labelling and the discrimination.

Comment: I have upvoted because this is the question I wanted to ask but I have no idea what do the corpora, distributed and semantic criteria mean.